# print(... , end='') sometimes not working

Tags: python

I have a 48x8 pixel image and I suspect there may be a hidden message somehow encoded in the RGB values. But when I try to tablulate the RGB values as ASCII characters using print(chr(...), end='') with this program, they all come out one per line:

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open("picture.png")
px=img.load()

for row in range(0, 8):
  if row > 0:
    print()
  for rgb in range(3):
    for col in range(0, 48):
      print(chr(px[col, row][rgb]), end='')
      if col == 16 or col == 24:
        print(' ', end='') 
      print()
```

And yet this:

```
print("Hello ", end='')
print("world")

for i in range(26):
  print(chr(65+i), end='')
print()
```

produces the expected output

```
Hello world
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Doubtless something silly if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: Why are you converting the RGB values to characters? They're not character codes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's basically a typo. (`print` indented too deep.) For debugging help in the future, please make a [mre] with minimal code, which will help catch basic mistakes like this.

Comment: You have a `print()` inside the inner `for`. One reason the python style guide encourages 4 space indentation is that its easier to spot code blocks and hence indentation mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Dedent the last `print()` statement one or two levels.